# Send Email with event.ics

Tags: email, outlook

I read few example for sending email with attachment of event.ics file, where user can open the file and it will add event to their outlook Celander.

Question is it possible to use link or content inside the email body instead the attachment file?

I'm looking something similar to the link that can be done for Google,
<a href="https://calendar.google.com/calendar/r/eventedit?..... target="_blank">Add to Google Calendar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either put a link to an ICS file in the email, or have it as an attachment. There's no way to make it inline or a URL that doesn't involve a server.

Comment: Thanks. I guess I will keep it as attachment.